# Можно ли вызвать метод без () типа class.method; вместо class.method();

Tags: c++

Можно ли вызвать метод без () типа class.method; вместо class.method();
Собственно это и есть вопрос

Comment: Конечно, нельзя.

Comment: учитывая, что методов нет в с++, то 100% нельзя.

Comment: макрос `# define` поможет. Так выглядит метод `errno`, например. `# define errno * fun_errno ( )`

Comment: @Harry, зависит от желания похимичить.

Comment: @KoVadim, почему нет методов?

Comment: @AlexGlebe, ну макрос к классу не привяжешь.

Comment: И кто там вопрос закрыть хочет, и, что особенно интересно, что у них не воспроизводится, если в вопросе кода нет?

Comment: Можно вызвать перегруженный унарный оператор. Например ++object; Это будет вызов метода, но без круглых скобочек.

Comment: @Qwertiy, есть функции_члены, а по некоторым  причинам понятие "метод" в С++ нет.

Comment: Нельзя, поскольку имя функции_члена принадлежит классу, а не объекту, и оно расположено по конкретному адресу(адрес функции_члена).  Х.method(); означает выполнить(с такими то аргументами) функцию_член  для объекта X, а Х.method это обращение к инкапсуляции,  в которую не входят функции_члены.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, в X.method() сам method может быть чем угодно. Там может быть указатель на функцию в самом инстансе, или вообще инстанс класса с перегруженным оператором, или что-то ещё. Неправильно связывать такую логику с синтаксисом. Синтаксис сам по себе, а ресолвинг имён и сущностей - сам по себе.

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя.

---

Но если речь о реализации свойств, то можно нахимичить что-то такое:

https://ideone.com/sQ18Sb (и даже сразу с выводом https://ideone.com/EL1ZKX)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
 
using namespace std;
 
template <typename T> class ro_prop
{
  private:
    const function<T()> get;
 
  public:
    ro_prop(const function<T()> &&get) : get(get) {}
    operator T() { return get(); }
};
 
struct rect
{
  int width, height;
  ro_prop<int> area = ro_prop<int>([this]() { return width * height; });
};
 
int main()
{
  rect a { 2, 3 };
  int s = a.area;
 
  cout << s << endl;
 
  return 0;
}
```

Или даже с макросом: https://ideone.com/utdjdS

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
 
using namespace std;
 
#define RO_PROP(T, N, G) ro_prop<T> N = ro_prop<T>([this]() { return G; })
 
template <typename T> class ro_prop
{
  private:
    const function<T()> get;
 
  public:
    ro_prop(const function<T()> &&get) : get(get) {}
    operator T() { return get(); }
};
 
struct rect
{
  int width, height;
  RO_PROP(int, area, width * height);
};
 
int main()
{
  rect a { 2, 3 };
  int s = a.area;
 
  cout << s << endl;
 
  return 0;
}
```

Но стоит учитывать, что такая абстракция будет течь в случаях, когда вместо реального типа в шаблон будет попадать тип свойства.

Comment: да, но тут a.area инкапсуляция(член)  класса, а не абстракция(функция_член)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, ты про то, что оно не в таблицу функций попадает, а в сам инстанс? Ну и плюс расходы на замыкание для лямбды. А компилятор не сможет оптимизировать? Или может что-то можно сделать, чтобы он оптимизировал?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, https://godbolt.org/z/9575h4G8c - что-то действительно длинновато получается.

Comment: Да, я об этом и говорю, но все таки трюк понравился.

Comment: У проперти шаблонным параметром должна быть сама лямбда, без std::function, чтобы оверхеда не было.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, а как это сделать? Если тип лямбды пихать в параметр шаблона, то тип при использовании фиг запишешь. А лучше я не придумал. Ну или делать указатель на функцию, принимающую this как аргумент, но тогда класс, в котором мы это используем, отправится в шаблон ro_prop и там придётся хранить хранить указатель. Можно лучше?

Comment: Сделал ответ. В итоге лямбду писать не стал, но `std::function` убрать смог.

Answer (score 1):

Нормальных способов нет, лучше напишите обычный метод.

---

Можно нахимичить что-то на шаблонах/макросах.

Продолжил мысль Qwertiy: ухитрился убрть `std::function` (которая занимает место, работает медленнее, чем прямой вызов функции, и не дает нормально скопировать объект из-за захваченного `this`), и добавил защиту от копирования поля наружу класса...

<kbd>[запустить на gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAHACspAAOqAqETgwe3r56KWmOAkEh4SxRMQm2mPYFDEIETMQEWT5%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%2BdFwAMTeUxTwsgwFAUPZlGIWDoiRHsOMMpkdr2xpEQgV88t1L951oAgDJiv1TpRc6IEsghtt216kRtW0rvy847oekbjq%2Bs6kQgF79oCt87QBm6qGBx6r3Bn7YbtM7mxIQ40PevjPuh86/oRoGvHulGryJ36HSxoglTyqHvphv6HVJ27yZBy8rwAP2pi72aRznHvU7jR2yzqUWPGNvlBvEnuZZMIloIsQHUkx4isTW43wBRRGIdANYw%2BJ8rpkgboamUoFOYr6toayviOD6JcYzBpeAS5WdPS6IoAKmW945kuoPrQ%2B9W1LBoVNO0vYIDBarokDNdUVEYZ4WdySZXdz3fcuOPMAT4gk4IFOmDTp2CfHBAGj2XPvYIBA8AUa1K1mj21PQ4PK0uf2VpDymM2MhW6QwuWR%2BizY7222UAHllGwWU%2BQATQgXlUTIiLN9feI3B7OjPrcG4%2BSNQMIcRdEY3XvY17ciwDh3nsFpEw/j9RU/0dROwqHRGVUQQKpXpXxvpdPY3dTwW3ulbWy9kIDFQpFSYqmcmIsR6hGI%2BJ9mbnQvt6MiN8yJ20ag3JuQ1%2BqDQOB3fKGtd7pTSEYPYL8MFn0/pKH%2BKIgEkRfM8fKcD2SIJyvCBhb9MFImwewtgL5ZZ3yoY/YS9D0FCKYa8d4Yi0Qh14pOT6YDsB7GKjbEA9UmDnxBm4AhVtjQADUbiohuLKE0QgfTgNVNHYgOkLFWJsXY40mF0L32ocPTWGsLBxlRG8PAABHLwaJDzoDBJtI2RsdEgHgbQYq/N4TSLBoI9%2BMNRG4I4QsDJCtNS2iycI8%2BX9WFojyeIuYxVSmKJWioiRD92LgLXheXxe8MSigPvI7JWD6g4OvvkzpJkpEtKKcyAAkotU0EZUQz1lKiNwAQbihBNBAPYqIdogSYBALsYE8ylkLImZMqYuzWm2VmPZBzcwQWOQmckpYwRjmkWYKs1ZggOxVugSsqAqBUCUEQC4D93kXL2NvPxqM9FpAAF5ok%2BmbYgl0QHOycWuGO/zAVrn%2BRAepH8KlESaQsYZNTvGUImajGZczLSLOWas9Zmyrm7P2e8w59yCyPJSHBd51pIWHVMuZKEfwp4MNUGRRE1oX6oggOKvYkqaQiq/PqORfIZVyslXsVQmxNiIgnjec4WzHwWi8cKjYU9qVgQWUslZayNmbwipc1EljrG2PsaiRVGwqhKE9Ra2ZVq6W2sZQ65SvwvVIQuIyH4%2B89jygcDSCOCtqp7AAO72QblwvYGgyL/xLAgT6uMs0D2nnPBey8mpgiYGRNN6AM2%2Bz2Lm4A%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)</kbd>

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


namespace impl
{
    template <typename T>
    struct SelfTypeReader
    {
        #if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
        #pragma GCC diagnostic push
        #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wnon-template-friend"
        #endif
        friend constexpr auto adl_GetSelfType(SelfTypeReader<T>);
        #if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
        #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
        #endif
    };

    template <typename T, typename U>
    struct SelfTypeWriter
    {
        friend constexpr auto adl_GetSelfType(SelfTypeReader<T>)
        {
            return U{};
        }
    };

    constexpr void adl_GetSelfType(); // Dummy ADL target.

    template <typename T>
    using SelfType = std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(adl_GetSelfType(SelfTypeReader<T>{}))>;

    template <typename Tag, auto Func>
    class Property
    {
        Property() = default;
        Property(const Property &) = default;
        Property(Property &&) = default;
        Property &operator=(const Property &) = default;
        Property &operator=(Property &&) = default;
        ~Property() = default;

        friend SelfType<Tag>;

      public:
        [[nodiscard]] operator decltype((std::declval<const SelfType<Tag> &>().*Func)())() const
        {
            return (reinterpret_cast<const SelfType<Tag> *>(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(this) - Tag{}())->*Func)();
        }
    };
}

#define PROPERTY(name_, ...) \
    struct CAT(_property_tag_, name_); \
    auto CAT(_property_self_type_helper_, name_)() -> decltype(void(::impl::SelfTypeWriter<CAT(_property_tag_, name_), decltype(this)>{})) {} \
    using CAT(_property_self_type_, name_) = ::impl::SelfType<CAT(_property_tag_, name_)>; \
    auto CAT(_property_func_, name_)() const -> ::std::decay_t<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)> {return __VA_ARGS__;} \
    [[no_unique_address]] ::impl::Property<\
        CAT(_property_tag_, name_),\
        &CAT(_property_self_type_, name_)::CAT(_property_func_, name_)\
    > name_; \
    struct CAT(_property_tag_, name_) \
    { \
        IF_GCC_OR_CLANG( _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push") _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Winvalid-offsetof\"") ) \
        std::size_t operator()() const {return offsetof(CAT(_property_self_type_, name_), name_);} \
        IF_GCC_OR_CLANG( _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop") ) \
    };

#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)
#define CAT_(x, y) x##y

#ifdef __GNUC__
#define IF_GCC_OR_CLANG(...) __VA_ARGS__
#else
#define IF_GCC_OR_CLANG(...)
#endif
 
struct Rect
{
    int width = 0, height = 0;
    PROPERTY(area, width * height)

    Rect() {}
    Rect(int width, int height) : width(width), height(height) {}
};
 
int main()
{
    Rect a(2, 3);
    int s = a.area;
 
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

В итоге, `PROPERTY(area, width * height)` раскрывается вот в такую красоту:

```
// Сначала узнаем, в каком классе находимся, и пишем тип в `_property_self_type_area`.
struct _property_tag_area;
auto _property_self_type_helper_area() -> decltype(void(::impl::SelfTypeWriter<_property_tag_area, decltype(this)>{})) {}
using _property_self_type_area = ::impl::SelfType<_property_tag_area>;

// Оборачиваем желаемое выражение в функцию.
auto _property_func_area() const -> ::std::decay_t<decltype(width * height)>
{
    return width * height;
}

// Создаем переменную своего класса, с перегруженным оператором преобразования.
[[no_unique_address]] ::impl::Property<_property_tag_area, &_property_self_type_area::_property_func_area> area;

// Узнаем смещение этой переменной относительно this, и задним числом сообщаем его нашей переменной.
struct _property_tag_area
{
    std::size_t operator()() const
    {
        return offsetof(_property_self_type_area, area);
    }
};
```

Comment: Ого, круто! Теперь надо разобраться, что тут происходит. Кажется, я процентов 30 только представляю...

Comment: @Qwertiy Тут половина - это [вот это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70701479/2752075) (определение типа класса, в котором мы находимся). А дальше вычисление его адреса, через адрес поля минус `offsetof` поля.

Comment: Хорошо бы никогда в жизни не столкнуться с поддержкой таких подходов.